# Remove a special character and Insert that to a line

Tags: linux, sed

How to remove a special character(#) from a big file and insert that character to a  particular line for example

input.tsv

```
$22  23   24  25  26  
33   33   34  35  36   
44   45   46  47  48  
ID  ID1   ID2 ID3 ID4
```

Output.tsv

```
22  23   24  25  26  
33   33   34  35  36   
44   45   46  47  48  
$ID  ID1   ID2 ID3 ID4
```

I've used the `sed -e 's/$//g' input.tsv` file to remove the '$' then how can I include '$' to the line starting with ID

Comment: Do you have only one line that begins with `$` and other unique line that begins with `ID` in the whole file?

Comment: Only One line that begin with **$**

Comment: How exactly does `sed -e 's/#//g'` remove `$` characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ sed -e 's/\$//g' -e 's/^ID/$ID/' file
22  23   24  25  26
33   33   34  35  36
44   45   46  47  48
$ID  ID1   ID2 ID3 ID4
```

Comment: `gunzip < file.gz | sed -e 's/\$//g'  -e 's/^ID/$ID/'`

Answer (score 0):

Just for the insert part

```
sed -i "/ID/,/ID/{s/^/#/}" input.tsv
```

Even simpler

```
sed '/ID/s/^/#/' input.tsv
```